# (-215:Assertion failed) while drawing matches in opencv

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv, feature-detection

I'm currently following this article: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html

When drawing the matches I get the following error:

```
error: (-215:Assertion failed) i1 >= 0 && i1 < static_cast<int>(keypoints1.size()) in function 'cv::drawMatches'
```

Through experience and a bit of reading I've seen that the -215 error code often shows up when there is a issue with the input image/matrix. I've checked to see if one of the two images I provide is broken in some way but I can't see the issue.

Here is the code in question:

```
def j_feature_match(src, needle):
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()
    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(src, None)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(needle, None)
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING2, crossCheck=False)
    
    matches = bf.match(des2,des1)
    matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
    
    src_img = cv2.drawMatches(src,kp1,needle,kp2,matches[:10],None,flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
    
    return(src_img, len(matches))
```

- EDIT: <s>As specified in a comment, the resolution of the images are as follows:
  src = 640x480
  needle = 300x400</s>
- EDIT2: I've changed out the images so I can share them.

1. [needle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBaTy.jpg)
2. [src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbR3W.jpg)

Thank you! :)

Comment: The error is not reproducible, it is probably related to the input images. Please edit your post, and add the input images `src` and `needle` (if you can).

Comment: The `src` image is taken directly from a webcam. The resolution of that image is 640x480, the `needle` image is a 300x400 image. I wanna add that I've tried to resize the images to match eachother, this did not work.

Comment: Directly from the webcam or not, is irrelevant... Save two images to files, if you have to. The important issue is posting a reproducible sample.

Comment: Images have been added to the post. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `drawMatches` [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d4/d5d/group__features2d__draw.html#gad8f463ccaf0dc6f61083abd8717c261a), `matches` argument is `matches1to2`.
That means that the matches should be from `src` to `needle` and not from `needle` to `src` (the order matters).

You may replace `matches = bf.match(des2,des1)` with

```
matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
```

Or change the order of the arguments of `cv2.drawMatches`:

```
import cv2


def j_feature_match(src, needle):
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()
    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(src, None)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(needle, None)
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING2, crossCheck=False)

    matches = bf.match(des2, des1)
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)

    src_img = cv2.drawMatches(needle, kp2, src, kp1, matches[:10], None,
                              flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

    return src_img, len(matches)


im1 = cv2.imread('src.jpg')
im2 = cv2.imread('needle.jpg')

res_im, n_matches = j_feature_match(im1, im2)
cv2.imshow('res_im', res_im)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Reading through the documentation again and now I see the issue clear as day. Great work!